# React app client-side routing not working on DigitalOcean App Platform

Tags: reactjs, react-router, digital-ocean, client-side-routing

I have deployed my React app to the DigitalOcean App Platform. The app uses client-side routing (e.g., React Router). The home page works correctly when visiting the root URL, but when I try to navigate directly to other routes by entering the URL (e.g., /auth/login), I get a 404 error (The requested page was not found). However, navigating within the app to that URL works as expected.

I have tried configuring catch-all routing using custom pages in the DigitalOcean dashboard, but it doesn't seem to work as intended.

How can I properly configure my React app on the DigitalOcean App Platform to handle client-side routing and serve the index.html file for all routes?

Additional context:

My React app is built using Vite.
I am using React Router Dom for client-side routing.
My app is deployed on the DigitalOcean App Platform using the default settings.

Comment: You will need to configure the hosting service/server to serve, or redirect to, the root index.html file for all page requests into the app. This isn't something you can fix client-side in the router. Take a look at the CRA [deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) to get a sense of the kinds of things different server environments require.

Answer (score 3):

Because this is a static site DO had a build entry but no start script equivalent to run serve etc.

Fix was having a Catchall within custom pages and simply specifying `index.html` as documented here:
https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/app-platform/how-to/manage-static-sites/

Initially, I tried it with `/index.html` which failed.

Comment: Yessss. Just adding the `_redirects` file didn't seem to work, but just catching all with `index.html` just worked!